# Non-administrative user rights in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm a little confused by this [table](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#authorisation), I need to create a user with rights to create and manage queues, but I can't figure out what rights I need to set

I don't want to use a rule like:

`rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p "custom-vhost"  "username"  ". *"  ".*"  ".*"`

What rights do I need to set the user so that he is not an administrator, but at the same time can create and manage queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RabbitMQ, the concept of "Administrator" only exists in the [management plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#permissions) (the HTTP API, which you can use through the HTTP website or `rabbitmqadmin`):

> The management UI requires authentication and authorisation, much like RabbitMQ requires it from connecting clients. In addition to successful authentication, management UI access is controlled by user tags. The tags are managed using rabbitmqctl. Newly created users do not have any tags set on them by default.

See the link for the description of the tags.

As such, if you give permissions to an user with `rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p "custom-vhost"  "username"  ". *"  ".*"  ".*"`, it won't be an "administrator", since it won't be tagged as such. It will just have perissions to create any queue and exchange, and to read/write message from/to any of them.